# How to access "hidden area" of SD Card in Android 11?

Tags: android-11

I have an unrooted Samsung A50 with Android 11 and have developer options activated.

---

I switch off my phone and remove the sdcard. Afterwards I mount the sdcard in my computer.

After mounting, I can see more than 360 files in the following path of the sdcard:

```
/Android/data/de.ard.audiothek/files/audio
```

---

Afterwards, I reinsert the sdcard in my phone and start it.

When I connect the computer with the phone, I cannot see any data below
/Android/data/
on the sdcard (everything else is visible).

If I use the most recent version of total commander on the phone and access the referring path

```
/storage/emulated/o/Android/data, there is a new link "-> Installed Apps".
```

as mentioned in https://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=72778 , I can just see one audio file there.

---

**Is there anything I can do (apart from rooting) to access these 360 files when the sdcard is in the running smartphone?**

Comment: Welcome Android Enthusiasts! Are 100% sure that `/storage/emulated/o/Android/data` is on your sd card and not the internal storage?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio : I can only comment on what I can find in the referred link ( https://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=72778 ). According to it, `/storage/emulated/o/Android/data` is just an artificial link to the sdcard data.

Comment: as the link already explains there is a change in android 11 and there is nothing you can do. side note: `sdcard` is actually not your MicroSD Card